# How to get the publish url after uploading video to azure media service?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

i am able to upload the video to windows azure media service by web HTTP rest API. but after uploading i am unable to get the URL to run this uploaded video in my browser. but video is running after the manually  publish in the azure port for this particular video.
 so how i can get the uploaded video publish URL by rest API (with out media service SDk) dynamically after uploading into media service.

=======
i am getting the multiple url. from this which one i have to select the perfect one. when i will do publish then i will  get one the url in azure portal for this particular video. but when my uploading and encoding done. i am getting multiple url.

My urls:

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_manifest.xml?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_H264_650kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_H264_400kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_H264_3400kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_H264_2250kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_H264_1500kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_H264_1000kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2_AAC_und_ch2_56kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D

https://portalvhdsd963vxvxn5lz8.blob.core.windows.net/asset-884f66e2-eb18-4952-88d8-80538ee6fd7c/smallwmv2.ism?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-10T16%3A54%3A51Z&se=2033-09-05T16%3A54%3A51Z&sr=c&si=83e1dcba-b296-4e08-b309-3cfb8ff360e0&sig=HzFbNn%2Fc5KuD%2B8UlArcoDR%2F5ZsF0Ca2Nlqgoq1SOw8g%3D.

Answer (score 2):

To get a URL for a published video, you would need to create something called a `Locator` in Media Services terminology. You would need to create a locator for the asset containing the published video. To create a locator, first you would need to create an `Access Policy` with `Read` permission (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974297.aspx#create_an_accesspolicy). Once that access policy is created, you would create a locator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974308.aspx#create_a_locator).

I wrote some blog posts on consuming Media Services REST API which you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/category/azure-media-service/. I wrote them long time back so some of the information may be outdated. Please reference REST API documentation for most up to date information.

Comment: i am creating all these steps. still i am not getting the path.

Comment: Are you getting some error? It would be helpful if you update your question with all the details including code if possible.

Comment: i am getting the multiple url. from this which one i have to select the perfect one. when i will do publish then i will  get one the url in azure portal for this particular video. but when my uploading and encoding done. i am getting multiple url.

Comment: If you look at the URLs above, you get files with different encodings/bit rates e.g. take a look at these two: smallwmv2_H264_650kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4 and smallwmv2_H264_400kbps_AAC_und_ch2_96kbps.mp4. Notice `650kbps` and `400kbps` in the file names. I guess you could pick any one of the MP4 file depending on your requirement.

Comment: @Gaurav, the link you have provided is broken, can you fix that?

Comment: @rajadilipkolli Fixed the link. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.