# How to get a published video URL

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm trying to build my app based on Windows Media Services REST API (**i'm not using any SDK**, just plain rest api requests).

My steps are more or less like:

1. Create Asset
2. Assign write Access Policy
3. Assign upload locator
4. Upload a file to URL specified by upload locator path
5. Assign download Access Policy
6. Assign download locator

All those steps seems to work great but - how can i actually get the video streaming URL? I can't see anything, which looks like such url (as far as i know, it should look similar to upload URL from upload locator). Should i "fold" it by myself using some segments from various parts of api ?

Based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129578.aspx#create_origin_URL_for_streaming), i should append the `path` parameter with `name` parameter and `/manifest` (so it should looke like that: `<path_param>/<name_param>.ism/manifest`) but it gives me `ResourceNotFound` error. Anyway, i've seen that other people (like [SHIBSANKAR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18682094/552936)) have found some way to obtain all asset urls so i think there is some way to do it but they have not descrbed how they've done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading all the docs and talking with microsoft support, i have figured it out. All the URL parts are returned by download locator and the formula looks like that:

```
#{BaseUri}/video.mp4#{ContentAccessComponent}
```

I hope someone will find that usefull someday.

Comment: I did! Thank you!

Comment: I spoke too soon, I needed to add the program's manifest name to the url - #{BaseUri}/#{Program.ManifestName}.ism/manifest